# Calculating total over timespan with arbitrary datapoints

Tags: algorithm

If I am given the total number of occurrences of an event over the last hour, and I can get this data at arbitrary times ( but at least once an hour ), how can I work out the total number of occurrences over a 24 hour period?

Comment: i have no idea what your question is.

Comment: You need to be a little bit more specific.  By "Total" do you mean current-total-on-hand? Or total received within a period? Or total received, ever?  Give us a simple example.

Comment: So it's a thing for Eve online. Their API gives the total number of kills in a system over the past hour. I will be calling that API roughly every hour, but because computers are computers, I can't guarantee that every datapoint will be on the hour. I want to calculate the total number of kills in a system over a 24-hour period.

Comment: @EddBC This context is important -- why not edit your question to include it?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you can't. For example -- if the first two observations overlap then it would be impossible to determine the number of kills during the overlap. If there is a time gap between the first two observations then there is no way to determine what happened during the gap. You could try to set up a system of equations -- but the resulting system will be underdetermined (but it could give you both a min and a max, which might be relevant).

Why not adopt a statistical approach? Let X = kills over a 1 hour period. This is a random variable. Estimate its expected value by sampling it at randomly chosen times and multiply your estimate by 24.